# The Unity3D plugin was unable to find it in expected locations?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins

I tried to run an Unity Build with Jenkins but got this failed build error in the console output.Is there anyone that can help me fix this problem? I couldn't find a solution online.

ConsoleOutput after failed build:

[image]

Comment: It's not the Unity build.  You have an issue with your repo.  Zip up what you've got an clone the repo again.  If you look at the error you're getting it says it cannot find it at the expected location.  Hopefully you'll be able to add your changes in to what you just pulled down.